# Exception in using objectify in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am writing a GAE program which use objectify. I download objectify-4.0b1.jar form [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/4.0b1/) and add modify WEB-INF/web.xml according to [this](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Setup). However, when I run my program, I got the following warnings. Another guy encoutered nearly the same problem as mine, but the solution may be different since I do use the latest jar file. It seems that com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter can not be loaded. Anyone can tell me why?

```
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-0c7af5c4835ec917(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
W 2013-02-19 22:52:33.149
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1687c76{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~zcbtest10/1.365432563369214216}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm using the latest objectify with GAE 1.7.5 on eclipse.

Comment: The most obvious answer is that your objectify jar is not deployed to GAE along with other stuff

Comment: @Peter How can I check whether or not the jar file has been deployed? If it isn't deployed, what I shall do? (The deployment is done by the plugin of eclipse.)

Comment: Look at @Romins answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please copy the Objectify JAR file in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of your project. This will make the Objectify classes available to the Web Container when it runs your application.

Comment: Do I have to copy the jar file to WEB-INF\lib? I just added the jar to  the build path.

Comment: Yes - you have to copy the file to the WEB-INF\lib folder.

Comment: OK! I guess I just asked a stupid question here:) and thanks for answering this stupid one.

Comment: No problem at all. I am glad your issue is addressed.

Comment: where do I find the objectify jar?

Comment: Go to https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/. The latest releases are found at the Maven repository but the older jars can be picked out from Google code repository.